# How to set Authentication Header of HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java

I need to set OAuth Authentication header of a HTTPS GET request and the header to be set is as follows

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" ,oauth_timestamp="1409861973" ,oauth_nonce="x1409861973681" ,oauth_version="1.0" ,oauth_signature="M+Dq62XboEd3+t6VDIcLy86zlQg="
```

I'm using the following java code below

```
String url = null;
    try {
        url = "https://secure.api.abc.net/data/ServiceAccount?schema=1.0&byBillingAccountId=" + URLEncoder.encode("{EQUALS,acc@xyz.edu}", "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String header = OAuthClient.prepareURLWithOAuthSignature(url1);

    HttpsURLConnection con = null;

    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", header);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("Response Code = " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        con.disconnect();
        //print result
        System.out.println("Response = " + response.toString());


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(con!=null) con.disconnect();
    }
```

It seems that con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", header) is not setting the Authorization header and hence server returns a 401.

Any idea how to resolve this.

Note: I tried to execute the same request from POSTMAN and this works fine there.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, changing only the url to `https://httpbin.org/get` and the header to a random word. The header was correctly sent in the request, so that doesn't seem to be the problem. Maybe your authorization header is incorrect? Try checking what `prepareURLWithOAuthSignature` actually returns.

Comment: prepareURLWithOAuthSignature returns the following header - OAuth oauth_consumer_key="vrnx4dpg6c356c6e8pp6ep74" ,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" ,oauth_timestamp="1409940580" ,oauth_nonce="x1409940580758" ,oauth_version="1.0" ,oauth_signature="y82y6Halc4Y9bcDuMgP1cxjSUsw="

Comment: Are you supposed to have an Authorization scheme before that string?

Comment: yes..in fact. It should be Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="vrnx4dpg6c356c6e8pp6ep74" ,oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1" ,oauth_timestamp="1409861973" ,oauth_nonce="x1409861973681" ,oauth_version="1.0" ,oauth_signature="M+Dq62XboEd3+t6VDIcLy86zlQg="

Answer (score 0):

You add the header in the correct way, and it seems you don't know whether the 401 error is caused by a missing `Authorization` header or by a wrong value in the header.

You should try and send your request to a website such as [myhttp.info](http://myhttp.info/) or [whatismybrowser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending) that will return back all the headers in your request. Just print them on the standard ourput, that way you will know for sure if the header is sent or not.

Comment: Thanks.. it seems that the header is sent with the request. Need to investigate why it throws 403 now? btw it throws 403 now.

Answer (score 0):

The Oauth signature appears to be missing the final URL encoding that is needed - I think. Should end in 3D with the equal sign encoded.